# Python removing words from strings

Tags: python, string, list, replace

My desired program has to read a text file like this:

```
EASTS versus WESTS
EASTS have scored 25:13
WESTS have scored 26:28
WESTS have scored 40:23
WESTS have scored 42:01
```

and run the following output:

```
WESTS 3
EASTS 1
```

I think i need to first put it into groups. Remove the newline characters. Then remove everything but the capital letters in the first line and assign them to seperate variables. Then search the text for the amount these variables occur. so that would mean a = 2 and b = 4 then - 1 off each total and have that as result. This is what i have so far:

```
import string
teams = []
for word in open('commentary.txt'):
  word = word[:-1] # gets away the /n characters.
  word = word.strip("versus") # This line doesn't work
  teams.append(word)
print(teams)
```

I think i know what to do but i dont know... Any help would be appreciated :D 
Thanks

Comment: Why are importing strings ? You are not using the module

Comment: Well this is an unintentional duplicate.. Plus i seem to be having a different problem.

Comment: I think your input is unclear and needs to be polished.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a dict or a counter for this. Something like this.

```
 from collections import Counter
 counter = Counter()
 for line in file:
     if 'versus' in line:
         continue
     words = line.split()
     counter[words[0]] += 1

 for team in counter:
     print team, counter[team]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the string method [count](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count). I would [join](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) the lines in the file, and then count how many times EAST and WEST occur in them.

Example code might be this:

```
def countwords(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        file_list = list(f)
        split_first_line = file_list[0].split()
        teams = (split_first_line[0], split_first_line[-1])
        for team in teams:
            print("{} {}".format(team, "".join(file_list[1:]).count(team)))
```